# Drupal Content Type field for spreadsheet

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-content-types

I am working on a Rental Home Listing website, where "Rental Home" is a content type with CCK fields.
I want to add a new field called 'Maintenance Log', which will be accessible only to the administrators and will be used to keep track of all maintenance work done on a home; it would have some functionalities a spreadsheet has.

I have already tried SheetNode & table types, but I ran into issues. Can anyone suggest a better alternative to implement this?

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested? As you have installed CCK, I guess you are not using Drupal 7, but you could be using Drupal 5 or Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the node_reference module which ships with CCK so all you have to do is enable it.

you would then create a new content type for maintenance logs, add a node_reference field to it that can reference nodes of type "Rental Home".

when someone has performed maintenance work on a home they would simply create a new maintenance log and use the reference field to reference the house in question.

then you can display these in a suitable way, using Views or the like.

if you'd like you can use the content access module to handle who can view the maintencene logs. you should also look at the content permissions module which also ships with CCK, it will allow you to specify access to specific CCK fields instead of the entire content type.